# Un-merge looping through sheets

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I want to select A1:A3 and unmerge on all sheets. This is what I have so far:

```
 Sub Unmerge()
   Dim rs As Worksheet
   For Each rs In Sheets
     rs.Range("A1:A3").Select
     Selection.Unmerge
   Next rs
   End Sub
```

My code only works on the first sheet then fails. Also my sheets are named differently, and the location of the workbooks will be different each time.

THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead..

```
Sub UnMerge()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 ws.Range("A1:A3").UnMerge
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: No sorry, it doesnt continue to the next sheet, I also added rs after next as a second attempt, with no success

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add rs.Range. Try it again.